# Grouping with multiple columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Contact` and `Account`, that contains following sample data:

`Account`

```
Account_Number | Account_Name
      1          ABC
      2          XYZ
```

`Contact`

```
ID | Account_Number | Contact_Name
1           1         Steve
2           1         Tom
3           2         Ryan
```

I want to identify all the `Account_Names` that contains multiple contacts associated.

Desired Output:

```
Contact_Name | Account_Name
Steve        | ABC
Tom          | ABC
```

I tried following query:

```
Select Distinct c.Contact_Name, a.account_Name
from Contact c
Inner join Account a
on c.Account_Number = a.Account_Number
group by a.Account_Name, c.Contact_Name
having count(Account_Name) > 1;
```

This query doesn't return anything, as the grouping is done against both `Contact_name` and `Account_Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aggregating only by the account, and then asserting that any matching account has at least two different contacts associated with it.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.account_Name
    FROM Account a
    INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.Account_Number = a.Account_Number
    GROUP BY a.Account_Name
    HAVING MIN(c.Contact_Name) <> MAX(c.Contact_Name)
)

SELECT a.account_Name, c.Contact_Name
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN Contact c
    ON c.Account_Number = a.Account_Number
WHERE a.account_Name IN (SELECT account_Name FROM cte);
```

[image]

### Demo

I wrote the `HAVING` clause this way because it leaves open the possibility that SQL Server may use an index on the `Contact_Name` column, should such an index exist.

Comment: I need both contact names and Account names in my result, is there any way we can add Contact names in result but only aggregate on Account Name?

Comment: @Aura Sorry, I did an about-face on my answer when I realized that you wanted the contacts as well.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: There are other ways to do it, e.g. using `EXISTS` instead of aggregating via `GROUP BY`.  My answer is probably the closest thing to what you were trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `exists`:

```
select a.account_name, c.contact_name
from account a join
     contact c
     on a.account_number = c.account_number
where exists (select 1
              from contact c2
              where c2.account_number = c.account_number and
                    c2.contact_name <> c.contact_name
             );
```

However, assuming that the contact names are unique, window functions are possibly simpler:

```
select a.account_name, c.contact_name
from account a join
     (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by c.account_name) as num_contacts
      from contact c
     ) c
     on a.account_number = c.account_number
 where num_contacts > 1;
```